# Enum.ToString() is returning default value instead of specified value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, tostring

I am trying to write a game, and I am using an enum to store colors of paint.
The enum keeps returning the default value instead of the value of the field. Is there a way to prevent this?

This is a C# .NET Forms application, for .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Here is my code:

```
public enum PaintColor
{
    Red,
    Orange,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Blue
}
class Form1 : Form
{

    private void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PaintBucket orange = new PaintBucket()
        {
            Color = PaintColor.Orange,
            Amount = 22
        };
        Label OrangeContent = new Label
        {
            Text = (orange.ToString()),
            Width = 100,
            Height = 20,
            Top = 500,
            Left = 500
        };
        Controls.Add(OrangeContent);
    }

}
```

And here is the defenition `PaintBucket` class:

```
public class PaintBucket
{
    public event EventHandler WriteToFile;
    PaintColor color = PaintColor.Red;
    int amount = 0;
    public PaintBucket()
    {
    }

    public PaintBucket(PaintColor col, int amnt)
    {
        this.Color = col;
        this.Amount = amnt;
    }
    public PaintColor Color
    {
        get => color;
        set{}
    }
    public int Amount
    {
        get => amount;
        set{}
    }
    protected virtual void OnWriteToFile(EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToFile(this, e);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return (this.Color.ToString() + ", " + this.Amount.ToString());
    }
}
```

As you can see above, the field `orange` contains an orange `PaintBucket`. The label `OrangeContent`, contains `orange.ToString`. But it shows up as `Red, 0` instead of `Orange, 22`. Red is the default value of the enum, and 0 is the default value for the integer. Is there a way to return the value of the fields instead of the default?

Comment: [Works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LL95q5). Please share code that illustrates a problem.

Comment: Please include the `PaintBucket` class implementation.

Comment: FYI, you can shorten your `ToString` method by using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated): `public override string ToString() { return $"{Color}, {Amount}"; }`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Look at your properties in `PaintBucket` class definition. You are returning an internal variable but you are not setting it.

Comment: @RufusL I will edit the code to include that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly disabling the setter (`set{}`) so a new value it will never get set. The constructor code `this.Color = col;` will do nothing.

You can define the property as

```
public PaintColor Color { get; }
```

to have a "constructor-settable only" property. You will need to remove the backingfield ("color") as it will not be used.

And for a default value:

```
public PaintColor Color { get; } = PaintColor.Red;
```

Comment: It works very well. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your properties to use the backing field:

```
public PaintColor Color
{
    get => color;
    set => color = value;
}
public int Amount
{
    get => amount;
    set => amount = value;
}
```

Or use auto-implemented properties:

```
public PaintColor Color { get; set; } = PaintColor.Red;

public int Amount { get; set; } = 0;
```